# Install sample-module-payment-gateway

Tags: magento-2.1

I'm new to Magento and Composer.  After being directed by the Magento site to  https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway, I noticed there was no way to clone the repo (at least none that I could figure out).  I read that you're supposed to install it using composer.  Sadly, I have no idea how to do that.  It would be nice if the readme provided steps.  I'm sure it's probably as simple as

```
composer install sample-module-payment-gateway
```

Any instructions anyone could offer would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In order to install anyone sample module you can download the specific folder with an online tool like [DownGit](https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home), for your case you can do the following:

1. Download only the sample-module-payment-gateway folder [here](https://minhaskamal.github.io/DownGit/#/home?url=https://github.com/magento/magento2-samples/tree/master/sample-module-payment-gateway)
2. In your Magento root folder create the directory
   `app\code\Magento\SamplePaymentGateway`
3. Paste all the content of the downloaded zip file in the folder
   described above, As you can see in the following image [image]
4. Then go to the terminal and run this sequence of
       commands (Note your need to be in the root folder of your magento
       installation):

   - `$ php bin/magento cache:disable`
   - `$ php bin/magento setup:upgrade`
   - `$ php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy`
5. And now you can check if the module is successfully installed with
       `$ php bin/magento module:status` or go to your Magento admin area in
       `stores/configuration/sales/Payment Methods`

And that's it (Tested in Magento 2.1.7).
I hope it helps you or someone else who has the same question

Greetings